# Testfor command not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Guys why is this testfor command not working?

```
/testfor @p firelordarmor 2 {Inventory:[{Slot:103b,id:"minecraft:skull",tag:{display:{Name:FireLord's Skull}}},{Slot:102b,id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",tag:{display:{Name:FireLord's Chestplate}}},{Slot:101b,id:"minecraft:leather_leggings",tag:{display:{Name:FireLord's Leggings}}},{Slot:100b,id:"minecraft:leather_boots",tag:{display:{Name:FireLord's Boots}}}]}
```

Comment: What is that supposed to test for? What is firelordarmor? What does the 2 in there mean? Look up the syntax of testfor, it's not that.

Comment: Also, the NBT is invalid in 1.12+. You need quotes around `"FireLord's Skull"`, `"FireLord's Chestplate"`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because of "firelordarmor 2". That's not a part of the command and shouldn't be there, delete it.

Also you need quotes around the names of the items. So the fixed command is:

```
/testfor @p {Inventory:[{Slot:103b,id:"minecraft:skull",tag:{display:{Name:"FireLord's Skull"}}},{Slot:102b,id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",tag:{display:{Name:"FireLord's Chestplate"}}},{Slot:101b,id:"minecraft:leather_leggings",tag:{display:{Name:"FireLord's Leggings"}}},{Slot:100b,id:"minecraft:leather_boots",tag:{display:{Name:"FireLord's Boots"}}}]}
```

The Minecraft wiki tells you the syntax for all commands. With it, you could have avoided the first problem.